# exercise in quadratic reciprocity law

Tags: number-theory

This is exercise 22 in chapter 6 of Ireland and Rosen's A classical intorduction to Modern number theory, which is a modified argument of Kronecker about the sign of Gauss sum:

Let $\chi$ be the quadratic character mod p given by the Legendre symbol, let $$g(\chi)=\varepsilon\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(\zeta^{2k-1}-\zeta^{-(2k-1)})$$ we want to show that $\varepsilon=+1$. Let $$f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\chi(j)x^j-\varepsilon\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(x^{2k-1}-x^{-(2k-1)})$$.
Then $f(\zeta)=0$ and $f(1)=0$, we have $x^p-1|f(x)$. Write $f(x)=(x^p-1)h(x)$ for some $h(x)\in\mathbb{Z} [x]$. Now let $x=1+t$ then compare coefficients of  $t^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ mod p of both sides.  To obtain that $\varepsilon =+1$ I need to show that $\sum_{j=\frac{p-1}{2}}^{p-1}\chi(j)\frac{j!}{(j-\frac{p-1}{2})!}\equiv -1$ mod $p$. Thanks

Comment: I think you should also say what is $\;\zeta\;$ . Probably a unit root.

Comment: Yes, $\zeta$ is $p$-th root of unity